# turtles think that they are always on a patch that is black

Tags: netlogo

i am making a model for a class in netlogo, but i have run into a problem, whenever a turtle asks the patch that it is on what color it is, it thinks that it is black, even when it is colored white

```
globals [var inside outside var1 ratio]
turtles-own [randomX randomY]

to setup
  reset-ticks 
  ask patches [set pcolor black]
  set var 0
  set var1 0
 while [var <= 360] [ask patch 0 0 [sprout 1 [set color white set heading var pd fd 100]]set var var + 0.15]
 ask turtles [die]
 tick
end 

to go
 ask patch 0 0 [sprout 1[]]
 check-location
 ask turtles [set randomX random 2000000 / 10000 - 100
 set randomY random 2000000 / 10000 - 100
 set xcor randomX
 set ycor randomY]
 tick
 reset-variables
end

to check-location
  ask turtles [ ask patch-here[if pcolor != black [set inside inside + 1]]]
  ask turtles [ ask patch-here[if pcolor != white [set outside outside + 1]]]
end

to reset-variables
  set outside 0
  set inside 0
end
```

I have a setup button, a go button with forever checked, a monitor that shows the variable inside, another monitor that shows the variable outside, and a monitor that shows `count turtles`. the outside monitor always shows the same number as the total monitor. any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the turtles pen down colors over the patches.  It does not change the color of the patches.  (You just cannot see that anymore.)  To changes the patch color, always use `pcolor`.

Comment: thanks, do you know what variable that is stored under, or a way that i could check for that

Comment: Never mind, I fixed it by having a repeat command and having the turtles going forwards one unit then changing the patch white thanks for your help